# Lynx Ubuntu problem

Tags: lynx

I encountered a tiny problem - my teacher suggested using `lynx -dump` to get website in file but for some reason, it 'returns' the previous state of the website. And if I disable the `-dump` option then it display how the current version of the website. Is there other way to get like text version of website? Does someone have any idea why it displays wrong text?

EDIT:
It looks like it has some delay. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Are you using the `-session` or `-sessionin` options?  There doesn't seem to be any other way for Lynx to possibly use a cached page.  If you aren't doing this, you'll need to provide more details because there isn't "some delay".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use

```
wget --recursive --no-cache
```